# Python : Value does not increase of variable in for and if loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop

The code is very simple, but I am not sure why the code is not increasing the value of variable num.

```
def cal(string):
    num = 0
    for w in string:
        if w.isupper():
            num = + 1

    print(num)


print(cal('My Name'))
```

it's print the value of num as 1 and answer should be 2.

Comment: it should be `num += 1`. Also your function doesn't return anything so printing the result of calling it doesn't make much sense. Consider `return num` instead of `print(num)` then you can print the result with `print(cal('My Name'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reversed the +=. Right now you are just assigning the num variable to +1 two times. Also you might want to return num instead of printing it, seeing that you are printing and calling the function at the bottom.

```
def cal(string):
    num = 0
    for w in string:
        if w.isupper():
            num += 1

    return num


print(cal('My Name'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting `num` to 1 each time instead of incrementing it. To increment it, use `num += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in the line:
   num =+1,
your're just saying that n is 1, and not increasing n.
You need to write n+=1.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe ..myself !!